# Swapping array problems in c

Tags: arrays, c, swap

I've been trying to swap array strings without using string.h or something else. I wrote some code but it only changes the word's first letter. Where did I make a mistake?

My code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 25

void strswap(char [], char []);

int main(void)
{
    char str1 [SIZE], str2 [SIZE];
    printf("enter the first string for strswap: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("enter the second string for strswap: ");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    strswap(str1, str2);
    printf("after strswap, the first string is %s, the second string is %s\n", str1, str2);
    return 0;
}

void strswap(char str1 [], char str2 [])
{
    char temp;
    temp=*str1;
    *str1=*str2;
    *str2=temp;
}
```

an example:

first string is: apple

second string is: hello

final result is: hpple & aello

Comment: `temp=*str1;` means assign the character at the `str1` address to `temp`. You aren't telling it to swap any more characters.

Comment: Karadelachu, Avoid buffer overruns - never use `"%s"` in `scanf()` without a _width_.  `scanf("%s", str1);` --> `scanf("%24s", str1);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str1` and `str2` are local to `strswap`. Any changes you make to those pointers will not be seen at the call site. Also, assigning a single `char` to `temp` like you do can not possibly swap the arrays.

If you want to swap the pointer values, provide pointers to the pointers.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 25

void strswap(char **str1, char **str2) {
    char *temp = *str1;
    *str1 = *str2;
    *str2 = temp;
}

int main(void) {
    char *str1 = malloc(SIZE);
    char *str2 = malloc(SIZE);
    if(!(str1 && str2)) return 1;
    
    printf("enter the first string for strswap: ");
    if(scanf("%24s", str1) != 1) return 1;

    printf("enter the second string for strswap: ");
    if(scanf("%24s", str2) != 1) return 1;
    
    strswap(&str1, &str2); // pointers to the char pointers
    
    printf("after strswap, the first string is %s, the second string is %s\n",
           str1, str2);

    free(str1);
    free(str2);
}
```

Comment: But it does not work with automatic arrays as in the OP example

Comment: @0___________ Nope. You got my vote for your version.

Answer (score 4):

To use a single pointer you need to **copy** the strings. In your code you only swap the first characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 25

void strswap(char [], char []);

int main(void)
{
    char str1 [SIZE], str2 [SIZE];
    printf("enter the first string for strswap: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    printf("enter the second string for strswap: ");
    scanf("%s", str2);
    strswap(str1, str2);
    printf("after strswap, the first string is %s, the second string is %s\n", str1, str2);
    return 0;
}

void strswap(char str1 [], char str2 [])
{
    char temp[strlen(str1)+1];
    strcpy(temp, str1);
    strcpy(str1, str2);
    strcpy(str2, temp);
}
```

Comment: Or better yet: `char temp[SIZE];` and you avoid VLAs

Comment: Everyone hates poor VLAs. Unfair.

Comment: I don't hate them :) in fact I was very upset when they were made optional.

Comment: @DavidRanieri good old gcc :)